# Default Branch or Tag in Github

Tags: github

I have an open source project on GitHub:
https://github.com/xrgarcia/alphavantage_api_client

When a visitor hits my landing page i want the REAME to point to a specific tag. At the moment it's 1.0.2.

How to set the default branch or tag for the landing page of my project?

I have tried looking at other GitHub projects (i.e. aws-sam) and i can see this is possible, but i haven't found the settings for it.

Comment: The steps for changing the default branch are specified in GitHub docs [here](https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/configuring-branches-and-merges-in-your-repository/managing-branches-in-your-repository/changing-the-default-branch).

Comment: Essentially it's in the repo under Settings -> Branches -> Switch to another branch (with a double arrow icon), where you can select and update the default branch for the repo.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. Thank you for pointing that out. this does answer my question, but i guess i want something GitHub doesn't offer yet. I would prefer a tag be something i could set as what visitors see. I don't want developers getting confused at the version of the README they are looking at versus the release. There are other ways i can deal with this :-).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would prefer a tag be something i could set as what visitors see

Since it is not practical to switch default branches (as it does not reflect a *tag*), an alternative would be to:

- keep you main branch
- update your `main/README` with an INSTALLATION section stating the exact tag you want the user to clone your repository with:

  ```
  git clone --depth 1 --branch <tag_name> <repo_url>
  ```

`--depth 1` is optional (shallow clone), but if you only need the state at that one revision, that would be enough.

---

However, nothing prevent you to make a branch named after a tag, and use that as your default branch.

That could also be a viable option.

Comment: Is there a negative side affect? I attempted to change the default branch as you recommended and GitHub gave me a message that, "changing the default branch can have unintended consequences".

Comment: @RayGarcia only for people having cloned the repository in the past, and cloning again? I will check that out once I am no longer on my phone in a train.

Comment: @RayGarcia Apparently, internet agrees: https://www.reddit.com/r/git/comments/3x71av/changing_default_branches_what_consequences/. Although it can have an inpact on tools and existing PR (https://docs.codeclimate.com/docs/changing-default-branch).